# how to get grid id as string in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to perform one operation by placing image in grid. Here I need to take id of two column from the grid, one is a hidden column and another is a normal column.

```xml
        <asp:LinkButton ID="Budgetid" runat="server" CssClass="EditLink" CommandName="EDIT" TabIndex="6"
            Text='<%#Eval("Budget_id") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hf_Bgid" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Budget_id") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Row_Status" Visible="false" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grid_header_text">
    <ItemStyle />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblRowStatus" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="OperationFont" Text='<%#Eval("Row_Status") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Budget code" SortExpression="Budget_Code" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Wheat" HeaderStyle-CssClass="grid_header_text">
    <ItemStyle Wrap="false" HorizontalAlign="center" />
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="BCode" runat="server" CssClass="OperationFont" Text='<%#Eval("Budget_code") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I have already got one value form the grid using

```cs
string strClid = ((HiddenField)row.FindControl("hf_Bgid")).Value.ToString();
```

Now I need to get the value of BCode as string like the `hf_bgid`.

I tried like this:

```cs
string strbudcode =  ((TemplateField)row.FindControl("BCode")).Value.ToString();
string strbudcode = ((Label)gvBudget.FindControl("Budget_code")).Text;
```

but `strbudcode` value always becomes null.

Comment: Control with `id="BCode"` seems to be `Label` but you're casting it as `TemplateField`. Control with `id="Budget_code"` seems to be a `TemplateField` but you're casting it as `Label`. May be if you fix that and try again.

Comment: so instead of string i should cast is as label ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to look up the value in your rowDataBound Event, you can just use labels for both but mark the column visible =false so it wont show on the page but you will have access to it from the code behind

```
  if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
     string strbudcode = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("BCode")).Text;
  }
```

Comment: Then just set visible=true in the HTML markup or from code behind.